# How do I design multi-role authorization on post requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

In the system I am building there is a complex and continuously changing resource-based authorization. There is a total of six roles at the moment.

The system is handling members where all members can edit basic info on their own profile, another person in another role can edit even more info on their profile and so on.

I cannot figure out which is the best way to design this with endpoints / actions for posts like the edit member action. What I ended up doing, but dislike, is that each role has one controller action, view and view model. The main reason for doing this instead of having one view model is that I felt it did not make sense to have all the properties that someone cannot even edit, that's over-posting right?

I am not quite happy with the result. 6 view models, 6 views, 6 madly similar controller actions, 6 validators etc.

My idea now is that I will just have one edit action and then have a bunch of if statements when mapping back to the domain object, in the view and on the validator classes. The overposting is still there but managed with if statements. I'm also thinking like this - what if the system would become an API? `api/members/1/edit/` makes more sense than `api/members/1/editAsTreasurer`?

What do you think? Anyone has another solution I have not thought of?

Some code parts, example of duplicated code, of course there's more in validator classes, views, and mapping, not sure how much to include:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditAsSecretary(EditMemberAsSecretaryViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        viewModel.Init(_basicDataProvider, _authorizationProvider.GetAuthorizedLogesForManageMember());
        return View("EditAsSecretary", viewModel);
    }

    var member = _unitOfWork.Members.GetByMemberNumber(viewModel.MemberNumber, true);
    if (member == null) return NotFound();

    // Authorize
    if (!_authorizationProvider.Authorize(viewModel.MemberInfo.LogeId, AdminType.Sekreterare))
        return Forbid();

    var user = _unitOfWork.Members.GetByUserName(User.Identity.Name);

    var finallyEmail = viewModel.MemberContactInfo.Email != null && member.Email == null &&
                       !member.HasBeenSentResetPasswordMail && member.MemberNumber != user.MemberNumber;

    _domainLogger.UpdateLog(viewModel, member, user);
    UpdateMember(viewModel, member, user.Id);
    _unitOfWork.Complete();

    if (finallyEmail) SendUserResetPasswordMail(member).Wait();

    TempData["Message"] = "Member has been updated.";

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Members", new { memberNumber = member.MemberNumber });
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditAsManager(EditMemberAsManagerViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        viewModel.Init(_basicDataProvider, _authorizationProvider.GetAuthorizedLogesForManageMember());
        return View("EditAsManager", viewModel);
    }

    var member = _unitOfWork.Members.GetByMemberNumber(viewModel.MemberNumber, true);
    if (member == null) return NotFound();

    // Authorize
    if (!_authorizationProvider.Authorize(member.LogeId, AdminType.Manager))
        return Forbid();

    var user = _unitOfWork.Members.GetByUserName(User.Identity.Name);

    var finallyEmail = viewModel.MemberContactInfo.Email != null && member.Email == null &&
                       !member.HasBeenSentResetPasswordMail && member.MemberNumber != user.MemberNumber;

    _domainLogger.UpdateLog(viewModel, member, user);
    UpdateMember(viewModel, member, user.Id);
    _unitOfWork.Complete();

    if (finallyEmail) SendUserResetPasswordMail(member).Wait();

    TempData["Message"] = "Member has been updated.";

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Members", new { memberNumber = member.MemberNumber });
}


private void UpdateMember(EditMemberAsSecretaryViewModel viewModel, Member member, string userId)
{
    _mapper.Map(viewModel, member);
    MapGodfathers(viewModel.MemberInfo, member);
    AfterUpdateMember(member, userId);
    _userManager.UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(member).Wait();
}

private void UpdateMember(EditMemberAsManagerViewModel viewModel, Member member, string userId)
{
    _mapper.Map(viewModel, member);
    MapGodfathers(viewModel.MemberInfo, member);
    AfterUpdateMember(member, userId);
    _userManager.UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(member).Wait();
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have added code examples.

Answer (score 1):

> My idea now is that I will just have one edit action and then have a bunch of if statements when mapping back to the domain object, in the view and on the validator classes. The overposting is still there but managed with if statements

Don't.

Besides making the code much less readable, it also poses a security risk. Every Action should take as little parameters as it needs. It does not cost you anything to have more Actions so there is no reason for doing that.

There are some issues though with your code, that help in that duplication:

1. You seem to be making security validations against what you receive from the user, instead of using the currently authenticated user. This is a big issue, as you are trusting the data that comes from a user.
   Instead of that, create a custom(s) Authorization Policy that checks for the type of user using your business logic. Those can be then added to the built-in container and you can use:

   ```
   [Authorize(Policy = "EnsureManager")]
   public IActionResult EditAsManager(...)
   ```

   This would allow you to remove all that duplicated code and be closer to the SRP.
2. Your duplicated `UpdateMember` looks like your models are unrelated. In a case like this, it would be far better to have a base model and then children with the required properties:

   ```
   public abstract class EditMemberBaseViewModel
   {
       [Required]
       public Something Something { get; set; }
   }

   public class EditMemberAsSecretaryViewModel : EditMemberBaseViewModel
   {
       [Required]
       public AnotherThing AnotherThing { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   That would allow you to have a single `UpdateMember` since the logic is based on `EditMemberBaseViewModel` and not their children, as far as you have shown that is:

   ```
   private void UpdateMember(EditMemberAsManagerViewModel viewModel, Member member, string userId)
   {
       _mapper.Map(viewModel, member);
       MapGodfathers(viewModel.MemberInfo, member);
       AfterUpdateMember(member, userId);
       _userManager.UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(member).Wait();
   }
   ```

As a last and probably most important point, there is a problem with this code:

```
_userManager.UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(member).Wait();
```

That's *really* bad. You are making ASP.NET Core hang an entire thread waiting for that action to complete. That's synchronous, 2000s code.
 You need to learn to use asynchronous code for every IO-related operation (like database calls) in your application, otherwise performance will suffer *lots*. As an example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditAsManager(...)
{
    .....
    await UpdateMemberAsync(...);
}

public async Task UpdateMemberAsync(...)
{
    await _userManager.UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(member);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, good input!

 Security validations are run on the current user (inside _authorizationProvider class IHttpContextAccessor is used.).

I don't think policies is sufficent since the authorization is resource based - I need to know in what loge the member to edit belongs to to authorize.

I'm actually already using inheritance but for some reason still reused that code. 

Yeah you got me, I don't understand async at all haha, thank you.

Comment: If this was an API, would you use

api/members/1/editAsManager
api/members/1/editAsSecretary

or

api/members/1/edit

And one command object per role?

Comment: @Lindeberg That doesn't look like REST to me. I would use something like `PUT api/members/1/manager` and `PUT api/members/1/secretary`, but don't take my word for it, that's my opinion. You should take the time to learn the basics of asynchrunous code in c#, it will take you much farther in your dev skills

Comment: Hi @Lindeberg, I wonder whether this answer helped you. You may want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)